# This dependency was not found: * worker_threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker

I previously tested and used `worker_threads` in my project.

Now when attempting to `npm run serve` or `npm run build` I'm getting the following error:

This dependency was not found:

- worker_threads

I am running `node --version  v14.17.2` so I know that `worker_threads` are supported.

I have even created a clean project with Vue CLI and when adding the following code, I still see the same error.

```
const {
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');
```

I've searched extensively, but all of the problems and solutions relate to earlier versions of the node that did not support it.

I'm at a loss as to how to solve this. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've updated all possible modules in the project in case there might be some sort of conflict, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

The code I wrote to use `worker_threads` was originally tested in a pure node.js (sever side) environment. The code ended up being required in a Vue component, which of course is browser based, so of course, `worker_threads` are not available as they are server side.

A solution would be to make a server API call to the code, or to use something such as [threads.js](https://threads.js.org/) which provides a unified API for `worker_threads` (sever side) and web workers which are browser based (client side).